# C# Cannot save data in Access 2007

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I cannot save data in access 2007. I tried the following:

- Add a password to my DB; didn't work
- Saved the db as a 2003 file; didn't work

Here is my code:

```
public bool ExecuteUDI(string query)
{
    Command = new OleDbCommand();
    Command.Connection = Connection;
    Command.CommandText = query;
    Command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    try
    {
        // Open connection
        Open();

        if (Command.ExecuteNonQuery() != -1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        mError = "ExecuteUDI - " + e.Message;
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Always close connection
        Close();
    }
}
```

When I add breakpoints, I see my query looks good:

```
INSERT INTO DVD (Titel) VALUES ('Elegy')
```

I don't get any errors, but the affected rows is 0. How come? I dont understand..

Comment: Could someone retag this issue? It's not taged "access 2007", it's tagged access and 2007... Feels wrong.

Comment: Where is your mdb file located in relation to your code?  I have had issues in the past that having the mdb file in the project folder will in essence create a local copy of the db in memory when the app is running, but nothing is actually written back to the mdb in the folder...

Comment: Thnx Dan, that was my problem. I put the mdb somewhere outside my project dir and it works. Thnx!!

Comment: Dan why don't you write up an answer so we can upvote you;-)

Comment: @ Josh, agree
@Austin my bad. Must be affected rows :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your mdb file located in relation to your code? I have had issues in the past that having the mdb file in the project folder will in essence create a local copy of the db in memory when the app is running, but nothing is actually written back to the mdb in the folder...

I recommend putting the mdb file outside your project's folder.  That should work.